# What's a good pattern to use to create desktop shortcuts pointing within network shares?

Tags: symbolic-link, cifs

I have a samba share set to mount in /media/foo when I boot, and on my desktop I have some symlinks pointing to locations within this share.

If my network flakes out, the symlinks report as broken, even after network connectivity is restored.

I either have to delete and re-create the symlinks, or restart the desktop environment in order to restore the symlinks.

Is there some other pattern I can follow that will be more tolerant of loss of network connectivity?

I have had this problem from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend mounting it via autofs. This is a service that will mount a directory on demand (for example if you cd into it or ls it) and unmount it automatically after a user defined timeout.

Install the autofs package for your distribution (by the way, remember to include your distro in your questions since an answer's details may depend on it).

```
Add the following to **/etc/auto.master**

    /media/[my_server] /etc/auto.[my_server]

Where /media/[my_server] is the mount point of the share.

    Create a file /etc/autofs/auto.[my_server] with this line:

    [any_name] -fstype=cifs,[other_options] ://[remote_server]/[share_name]
```

For further details please refer the link given below

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs#Samba

Comment: In my case I have had the same problem from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 14.04. I will give this a shot and see how it behaves with symlinks.